# How To select Faces from a face map using Python?

Tags: python, select

I am trying to find a way to select faces from a face map, without using the select operator in the given, I know u can do it by

```
bpy.ops.object.face_map_select()
```

But I am trying to find a way to select it using faces or bmesh or something, but I cannot, Is it even possible without the operator above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is more efficient than `bpy.ops` in this case, but you can:

```
import bpy

# get an object
o = bpy.context.object

# get one of its face maps
face_map = o.face_maps['FaceMap']

# get its index
face_map_index = face_map.index

# run over the data of the face map data layer (only one layer, so [0])
for i, fm_data in enumerate(o.data.face_maps[0].data):
    # select the polygon if its fm layer value correspond to the good face map
    # fm_data.value can be either -1 (unassigned) or the index of the face map it is assigned to
    o.data.polygons[i].select = fm_data.value == face_map_index
```

**Note**: this code won't work in edit mode (will no nothing).

Comment: Thank you, Yes it works as expected, It's better than ops as in giving more flexibility to my code, I was actually trying face_map.items(), values(), but didn't realize there was ".data", Appreciate it.

Comment: Can you Explain me {o.data.face_maps[0].data}, what is significance of using [0] in there (index tho, but index of what?)?, is it accessing facemaps from object's facemaps, Cuz there are two ways face_maps occur in objects, either by obj.face_map or obj.data.face_maps, what's difference between both?, or something else, cuz I got some error while playing with the value,

Comment: Object face map is the level where face map are defined (as visible in the object property panel). But the data in inside the obj.data (as usual). `o.data.face_map[0]` is the layer where the data is. There is only one layer available at the moment, so always '0'. In this layer there is an array called "data" which contains the link of each face to its face map.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Much appreciated.